# How can I sort a dictionary by value in alphanumeric order with Python?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Im having a problem while sorting my dictionary with alphanumeric values. Each value has at least one letter in front (sometimes two) followed by some numbers. Example:

```
shoppingList = {'milk': 'W30', 'eggs': 'W29', 'tuna': 'W3', 'gum': 'CL24', 'beans': 'W6'}
```

When Im sorting it:

```
sorted_dict = sorted(shoppingList.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1))

for i in sorted_dict:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
('gum', 'CL24')
('eggs', 'W29')
('tuna', 'W3')
('milk', 'W30')
('beans', 'W6')
```

So it seems the sort is only using the first number it comes across. Is there a way to get the output as

```
('gum', 'CL24')
('tuna', 'W3')
('beans', 'W6')
('eggs', 'W29')
('milk', 'W30')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its sorting strings, not numbers, you need to parse the integer

Comment: You could split the values into a separate letter then number. Make sure to cast the number to int so it isn’t treated as separate digits. Your key would be `lambda x: x[1], x[2]` where the tuples are `(name, letter, number)`

Comment: FWIW, the dict is beside the point. You could reproduce the same sorting behaviour with a list.

Comment: ah, yes... very true. That makes total sense now. haha. thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its sorting strings, not numbers, you need to parse the integer.

The one line approach would be ugly, so i'd be tempted to convert the given key below into a seperate function that can handle the splitting of the list

```
sorted(
    shoppingList.items(),
    key=lambda k: (
        ''.join(x for x in k[1] if not x.isdigit()),
        int(''.join(x for x in k[1] if x.isdigit())) 
    )
)
```

```
 [('gum', 'CL24'), ('tuna', 'W3'), ('beans', 'W6'), ('eggs', 'W29'), ('milk', 'W30')]
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The module [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) will do this in the order you want.

```
from natsort import natsorted
from operator import itemgetter

D = natsorted(shoppingList.items(), key=itemgetter(1))

[('gum', 'CL24'), ('tuna', 'W3'), ('beans', 'W6'), ('eggs', 'W29'), ('milk', 'W30')]
```